# M1 Mac says it can not find PyAudio, however I can access the version of it I have

Tags: python, pyaudio, portaudio

So I recently wanted to just mess around with voice recognition tools in Python, and unfortunately can't even get started! I have tried using brew to install portaudio and pip for PyAudio, which to my avail, actually exists on my mac!

Running `pip show pyaudio`, I get this:

```
Name: PyAudio
Version: 0.2.11
Summary: PortAudio Python Bindings
Home-page: http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/
Author: Hubert Pham
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /Users/jacob/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

So it does exist on my mac, however when trying to actually use the package, I get this as a result.

```
Could not import the PyAudio C module 'pyaudio._portaudio'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jacob/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio
  File "/Users/jacob/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyaudio/__init__.py", line 111, in <module>
    import pyaudio._portaudio as pa
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/jacob/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyaudio/_portaudio.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_PaMacCore_SetupChannelMap'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "voiceRecog.py", line 3, in <module>
    mic = sr.Microphone()
  File "/Users/jacob/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "/Users/jacob/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

I have tried looking through lots of posts and forums, and still nothing has been able to help, so any help or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: The paths seem to indicate Anaconda, not Homebrew. If you have Anaconda, did you try to install using that? How is your Python set up in the first place?

Comment: Personally, I would use Nix -- one of the big advantages is reproducibility; when you ask Nix for a specific Python environment it's assembled in isolation so how you installed other tools on the same machine in the past can't break it.

Comment: as an example, `nix-shell -p '(let pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {}; in pkgs.python311.withPackages(p: [p.pyaudio]))'` sets you down in a shell in which you can run `python` and then successfully `import pyaudio`.

Comment: @tripleee I originally had python downloaded from python itself, but later had to install anaconda for school reasons.

Running it with conda install i get the following
"
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

Retrieving notices: ...working... done
"